# Remove duplicates and manipulate dataframe based on conditions from 2 columns

Tags: r, while-loop, dplyr, grouping, cluster-analysis

I've a dataframe as under

```
+------+-----+----------+--------+
| from | to  | distance | weight |
+------+-----+----------+--------+
|    1 |   8 |        1 |     10 |
|    2 |   6 |        1 |      9 |
|    3 |   4 |        1 |      5 |
|    4 |   5 |        3 |      9 |
|    5 |   6 |        4 |      8 |
|    6 |   2 |        5 |      2 |
|    7 |   8 |        2 |      1 |
|    4 |   3 |        5 |      6 |
|    2 |   1 |        1 |      7 |
|    6 |   8 |        4 |      8 |
|    1 |   7 |        5 |      3 |
|    8 |   4 |        6 |      7 |
|    9 |   5 |        3 |      9 |
|   10 |   3 |        8 |      2 |
+------+-----+----------+--------+
```

I want to sequentially filter the data based on the criterias below:

1. If a number appears in the `to` column it shouldn't be repeated in either the `to` or the `from` column
2. The number in `from` can be repeated if its correponding `to` is a new value and isn't available in any of the cells in the `to` column
3. I want to repeat this process until all the unique values from the `from` and `to` combined appear atleast once in either of the columns
4. If a number in the `from` column is a new number and if its correponding `to` value is already present in either of the columns then replace that `to` and distance value with a blank

So the resulting table would look as under:

```
+------+-----+----------+--------+
| from | to  | Distance | weight |
+------+-----+----------+--------+
|    1 |   8 |        1 |     10 |
|    2 |   6 |        1 |      9 |
|    3 |   4 |        1 |      5 |
|    1 |   7 |        5 |      3 |
|    9 |   5 |        3 |      9 |
|   10 |     |          |      2 |
+------+-----+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your conditions? It is unclear to me how your logic is working here. For example, in the first condition you said, "If a number appears in the `to` column it shouldn't be repeated in either the to or the from column." There are two rows containing `5` in `to`. You have the 13th row in the final result. Why not the 4th row? I have no clue about the 2nd condition. Can you explain your logic in a different way so that people can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: @jazzurro, thats because the number 4 in the "from" column of the 4th row is already present in the "to" column

so to prevent it from being repeated I chose the 13th row

Comment: @jazzurro as for the second condition, lets consider the 1st and the 11th rows, although the from column already has a cell with value 1, it still repeated again as the corresponding `to` column has a value (7) thats new to the `to` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt to reproduce the expected result according to OP's rules.

I am still struggling to find a solution using `unique()`, `duplicated()` on the data in wide format as well as reshaped to long format.

However, here is a solution using a `for` loop which reproduces the expected result for the given sample dataset:

```
library(data.table)
# append row numbers
setDT(DT)[, rn := .I]

# which values appear only once in the `to`` column?
single_to <- DT[, .N, by = to][N == 1L, to]
single_to
```

> ```
> [1] 2 1 7
> ```

```
DT[, drop := NA]
for (i in seq_len(nrow(DT))) {
  print(i)
  print(DT[i])
  if (isTRUE(DT$drop[i])) next # row already has been eliminated
  act_to <- DT$to[i]
  # Rule 1: eliminate subsequent rows with repeated value in `to` column  
  DT[rn > i & (to == act_to), drop := TRUE]
  # Rule 1: eliminate subsequent rows with repeated value in `from` column 
  # Rule 2: but keep rows where value is unique in the `to` column  
  DT[rn > i & (from == act_to) & !(to %in% single_to), drop := TRUE]
  DT[i, drop := FALSE]
  print(DT[])
}
```

> ```
> [1] 1
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    1  8        1     10  1   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2    NA
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3    NA
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4    NA
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5    NA
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6    NA
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8    NA
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9    NA
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11    NA
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13    NA
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14    NA
> [1] 2
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    2  6        1      9  2   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3    NA
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4    NA
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5  TRUE
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6    NA
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8    NA
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9    NA
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11    NA
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13    NA
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14    NA
> [1] 3
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    3  4        1      5  3   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4  TRUE
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5  TRUE
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6    NA
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8  TRUE
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9    NA
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11    NA
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13    NA
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14    NA
> [1] 4
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    4  5        3      9  4 TRUE
> [1] 5
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    5  6        4      8  5 TRUE
> [1] 6
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    6  2        5      2  6   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4  TRUE
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5  TRUE
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6 FALSE
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8  TRUE
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9    NA
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11    NA
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13    NA
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14    NA
> [1] 7
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    7  8        2      1  7 TRUE
> [1] 8
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    4  3        5      6  8 TRUE
> [1] 9
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    2  1        1      7  9   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4  TRUE
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5  TRUE
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6 FALSE
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8  TRUE
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9 FALSE
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11    NA
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13    NA
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14    NA
> [1] 10
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    6  8        4      8 10 TRUE
> [1] 11
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    1  7        5      3 11   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4  TRUE
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5  TRUE
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6 FALSE
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8  TRUE
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9 FALSE
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11 FALSE
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13    NA
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14    NA
> [1] 12
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    8  4        6      7 12 TRUE
> [1] 13
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:    9  5        3      9 13   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4  TRUE
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5  TRUE
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6 FALSE
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8  TRUE
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9 FALSE
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11 FALSE
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13 FALSE
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14    NA
> [1] 14
>    from to distance weight rn drop
> 1:   10  3        8      2 14   NA
>     from to distance weight rn  drop
>  1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
>  2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
>  3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
>  4:    4  5        3      9  4  TRUE
>  5:    5  6        4      8  5  TRUE
>  6:    6  2        5      2  6 FALSE
>  7:    7  8        2      1  7  TRUE
>  8:    4  3        5      6  8  TRUE
>  9:    2  1        1      7  9 FALSE
> 10:    6  8        4      8 10  TRUE
> 11:    1  7        5      3 11 FALSE
> 12:    8  4        6      7 12  TRUE
> 13:    9  5        3      9 13 FALSE
> 14:   10  3        8      2 14 FALSE
> ```

The result so far differs from the expected result

```
result <- DT[!(drop)]
result
```

> ```
>    from to distance weight rn  drop
> 1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
> 2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
> 3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
> 4:    6  2        5      2  6 FALSE
> 5:    2  1        1      7  9 FALSE
> 6:    1  7        5      3 11 FALSE
> 7:    9  5        3      9 13 FALSE
> 8:   10  3        8      2 14 FALSE
> ```

Rows 1 to 3, 11, 13, and 14 are in line with the expected result but rows 6 and 9 are kept, here, because values `2` and `1` are unique in the `to` column.

Obviously, this approach needs to be refined as `2` and `1` already have appeared in the `from` column of rows 1 and 2, resp. These rows need to be removed as duplicates.

In order to remove these, `result` is reshaped from wide to long format and ordered by row number:

```
ldt <- melt(result, "rn", c("to", "from"))[order(rn)]
ldt
```

> ```
>     rn variable value
>  1:  1       to     8
>  2:  1     from     1
>  3:  2       to     6
>  4:  2     from     2
>  5:  3       to     4
>  6:  3     from     3
>  7:  6       to     2
>  8:  6     from     6
>  9:  9       to     1
> 10:  9     from     2
> 11: 11       to     7
> 12: 11     from     1
> 13: 13       to     5
> 14: 13     from     9
> 15: 14       to     3
> 16: 14     from    10
> ```

Now, we need to identify the row numbers of the duplicates which belong to the `single_to` values:

```
ldt[duplicated(value) & variable == "to" & value %in% single_to]
```

> ```
>    rn variable value
> 1:  6       to     2
> 2:  9       to     1
> ```

These rows are removed from `result` by an *anti-join*:

```
result2 <-
  result[!ldt[duplicated(value) & variable == "to" & value %in% single_to], on = .(rn)]
result2
```

> ```
>    from to distance weight rn  drop
> 1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
> 2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
> 3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
> 4:    1  7        5      3 11 FALSE
> 5:    9  5        3      9 13 FALSE
> 6:   10  3        8      2 14 FALSE
> ```

This is now nearly in line with the expected result. Only rule 4 needs to be implemented. For this, the same approach as before is used: reshaping to long format, identifying the row numbers and joining. However, here an *update join* is used:

```
ldt2 <- melt(unique(result2, by = "from"), "rn", c("to", "from"))[order(rn)]
result2[ldt2[duplicated(value)], on = .(rn), c("to", "distance") := NA_integer_]
result2
```

> ```
>    from to distance weight rn  drop
> 1:    1  8        1     10  1 FALSE
> 2:    2  6        1      9  2 FALSE
> 3:    3  4        1      5  3 FALSE
> 4:    1  7        5      3 11 FALSE
> 5:    9  5        3      9 13 FALSE
> 6:   10 NA       NA      2 14 FALSE
> ```

#### Discussion

This solution does not claim to be efficient in terms of coding or execution speed. It just aimes at reproducing the expected result from the given sample dataset.

It needs much more testing. For instance, the OP has requested in rule 3

> I want to repeat this process until all the unique values from the
> from and to combined appear atleast once in either of the columns

By implementing rules 1 and 2, there is no check that this condition is met, finally.

Also, I believe there might be other ways to achieve the same goal.